# How to install SOAP extension on PHP-FPM 5.5.6 - dependency issue

Tags: centos, php-fpm, soap

I have a problem with installing SOAP extension for PHP-FPM 5.5.6 (both 32 + 64 bit) with nginx on CentOS 6.4. I have enabled REMI repos and installed everything succesfully - except the SOAP extension.

When trying to install I am receiving following dependency error:

```
[root@local src]# yum --enablerepo=remi install php-soap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.hexageek.com
 * epel: mirror.digmia.com
 * extras: mirror.hexageek.com
 * remi: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * updates: mirror.hexageek.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:5.4.22-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.22-1.el6.remi for package: php-soap-5.4.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-soap-5.4.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.22-1.el6.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.5-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.5-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.21-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.22-1.el6.remi
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Installing from remi-test "yum --enablerepo=remi-test install php-soap" shows even older version php-soap 5.3.3.

Here's what I tried so far:

1/
pear install soap    .... cannot install version 0.13.0 is not preferred stable, use channel 0.13.0 ... but I was not able to do it, how to switch channel..no clear documentation or not working...

2/

yum --enablerepo=remi install php-soap   .... dependency issue for soap 5.4.22

yum --enablerepo=remi-test install php-soap   .... dependency issue for soap 5.3.3

3/
I downloaded RPM from [RPM downloaded packages](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php-soap&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=) and tried
yum localinstall  php-soap-5.5.6-1.fc20.remi.x86_64.rpm  ... again dependency issue

Does anyone succeeded in installing PHP SOAP extension on PHP 5.5.6 with PHP-FPM?

I also checked at [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php) but there is no info about anything, just "**configure PHP with --enable-soap**" which sounds like SOAP extension is already bundled into core .. ? I really need this extension badly and I dont want to downgrade PHP version.

Thanx a lot for any good advice:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the output carefully again:

```
Installed: php-common-5.5.5-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
```

Using

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php55 install php-soap
```

should help. Check this [link](http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2013/10/03/New-repository-remi-php55).

And please do not try to install Fedora packages on CentOS.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my life:-) now it works and installed soap and also igbinary. Now I understand also how to interpret dependency messages:-)

Comment: This answer is heavily underrated. It deserves more upvotes.